# Gray unusable area on CE Winforms form

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

Did test app for Windows CE Winforms App.

Main form has about 30 px gray area between the form header and the actual content.

On the device itself (not emulator). CF 3.5 CE 6.0

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Menu from the Form or add MenuItems to it.

[image]